# Expo react native - Running timer in background

Tags: react-native, timer, expo, setinterval

I'm currently building an Fitness app in react native. Therefore I need a timer in between sets the user is performing. Is there a way to run a timer in the background?

setInterval() sadly stops when locking the screen of my device. I found the following package [React Native Background Timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-timer), which I can't use when working with expo.

I also found the [Expo Background Fech / Task Manager](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v47.0.0/sdk/background-fetch/) Methods from Expo but I red that it's not updating consistently on the interval time. So thats also useless to me.

Do somebody know a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and figured out a super hacky way to get around this. My app already uses the Expo AV library for audio playback, including continuing to play audio in the background when the screen is off or app is backgrounded. However, I need my own custom timer to continue firing periodically during that time, and on Android, my own timer created with `setInterval` gets killed immediately as soon as the app is backgrounded.

However, if you have your app configured to play audio in the background (see the Expo AV docs for this, it's straightforward), the playback status listener for your audio will continue to fire in the background. You can set the timer interval in the initial configuration. So if you set up a sound with:

```
const soundInitialStatus = {
  ...
  isLooping: true,
  progressUpdateIntervalMillis: /* your update interval */
};
```

and then add a listener, like

```
const sound = new Audio.Sound();

sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(function(playbackStatus) {
  console.log('This will fire even when the app is backgrounded')
});

await sound.loadAsync(/* resource */, soundInitialStatus);
sound.playAsync();
```

Now comes the crazy hack, which is, even if for your app you don't need to be constantly playing audio in the background, you can create a short sound that's just silence and set it up this way to keep looping, and you'll get your background timer.

For me this works great as my app is already playing various sounds in the background and adding one more layer of silence that's always looping in the background is an acceptable hack. It may not be for others, but figured I'd share it just in case, given that there's really no other proper solutions to this out there, other than the two that OP already mentioned which didn't work for me for the same reasons.